# How to assign a user control to a namespace without having code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, namespaces

In a normal user control, we have .cs.ascx (code-behind) to assign the namespace we want our control to be in. But what if we don't have this code-behind to assign the namespace? Can we maybe assign the namespace of a user control in the headers?

**EDIT**
I was hoping I can do somthing like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Namespace="ThisIsTheNamespaceIWantMyControlToBeIn.Controls" %>
<b>Hello World!</b>
```

Comment: Post code of how you want to do it and then people can tell you if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are asking for makes no real sense. The namespace that is specified in the code-behind file is the namespace for that class in the code behind file.

The code in the .ascx file is dynamically compiled into a new class that derives from the class in your code behind file. But this class is placed in a completely different namespace (I think that it will be in a namespace named ASP)

So if you don't have a code-behind file (I didn't even think that would be possible) then there is nothing to set the namespace for.

Comment: Yes you're right. Well the intent of this question is to see if I can get my controls registered in web.config <system.web><pages><controls> without having code-behind in my ascx file. Maybe that should have been a better question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

`<%@ Control %> and <%@Reference %>` tags with the tag namespace in the reference of the receiving page?  I'm not sure if that fits what you're asking for.